# Object array to csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python. I cant get correct guidance for the below problem.

I have an object array as follows:

```
[{"key1":22,"key2":33},{"key1":55,"key2":66}]
```

I want to convert this into csv as follows:

```
key1  key2
22    33
55    66
```

Can you please guide me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use pandas dataframe structures. Let `d` be your dictionary, you can build a dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

and then save it to csv with:

```
df.to_csv('yourfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: pandas is not the tool to create a csv unless you actually want a dataframe which the OP does not seem to want

Answer (score 5):

Constructing a DataFrame just to create a csv file does not make much sense, a `csv.DictWriter` is designed to do exactly what you want:

```
import csv

d = [{"key1":22,"key2":33},{"key1":55,"key2":66}]
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter="\t",fieldnames=list(d[0].keys()))
    wr.writeheader()
    wr.writerows(d)
```

If you want the columns in alphabetical order you will also need to sort the keys as dicts are unordered so use `fieldnames=sorted(d[0].keys())`.